# Single quote character in Swift

Tags: swift

Trying to add a single quote `'` character in my code in Swift, but it's constantly adding a `\'` and this is necessarily for an API Call.

My code is:

```
let locationLat = String(format: "%f", (currentLocation?.coordinate.latitude)!)
let locationLong = String(format: "%f", (currentLocation?.coordinate.longitude)!)
let apiLocation = "$filter=geo.distance(Location,geographyPoint" + "(" + locationLat + locationLong + ")) le 0.1"
```

I need to make the apiLocation variable look like:

```
$filter=geo.distance(Location, geography'POINT(lat, long)') le 0.5&searchMode=all&$count=true
```

Let me know thanks.

Comment: Where's the actual quote...? Btw you can just use `toString)` on float/double, no need for `String(format:)`

Comment: And you don't need to escape `'`, just type it inside the string and use [interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292) for your variables.

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

Using escape character for single quotes `\'` = `'` and interpolation (`\()`)for variables you can achieve this in one string.

```
let apiLocation = "$filter=geo.distance(Location, geography\'POINT(\(locationLat), \(locationLong))\' le 0.5&searchMode=all$count=true"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 5, below code worked for me

```
let myText = #"'"#
print(myText)
```

Output

```
'
```

[image]

Comment: There's no need to use raw strings in this case. Single quotes no longer have to be escaped. `let singleQuote = "'"` works just fine.